# How to access the "Airship Rising" synthesizer/mode in GarageBand iOS (iPhone)?

Tags: garage-band

Around a year ago my friend and I were using GarageBand on their MacBook with a MIDI keyboard attached to it. I believe there was a GarageBand synth mode named "Airship Rising".

After installing GarageBand on my iPhone, I wanted to use this mode
(Airship Rising) with the on-screen keyboard. However, after scrolling through basically every available option I could see, I was not able to find it.

Anyone know if it's accessible on a mobile device, and if so, how to access it?

Comment: This is not a recommendation for specific equipment or soundfonts. This is a request for help about how to access specific soundfonts that should come with Garageband. See https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/98462/tapping-noise-when-using-airship-rising-garage-band for an example of a question that presumes that "Airship Rising" can already be accessed in Garageband. As a result, I voted to reopen this.

Comment: Agree with @Dekkadeci. OP edited to make clear this is seeking assistance in using the app itself, not requesting software to use with it. Also voted to reopen.